# For loop with 2 variables after "in"

Tags: python

I am confused about the following statement

```
for sentence in snippet, phrase.
```

Why there are two items behind the "in"

**Full Code**

```
def convert(snippet, phrase):
    class_names = [w.capitalize() for w in
                   random.sample(WORDS, snippet.count("%%%"))]
    other_names = random.sample(WORDS, snippet.count("***"))
    results = []
    param_names = []

    for i in range(0, snippet.count("@@@")):
        param_count = random.randint(1,3)
        param_names.append(', '.join(random.sample(WORDS, param_count)))

    for sentence in snippet, phrase:
        result = sentence[:]

        # fake class names
        for word in class_names:
            result = result.replace("%%%", word, 1)

        # fake other names
        for word in other_names:
            result = result.replace("***", word, 1)

        # fake parameter lists
        for word in param_names:
            result = result.replace("@@@", word, 1)

        results.append(result)

    return results
```

Comment: With `snippet, phrase` you're creating a `tuple` which can be iterated. It might look more familiar to you like this: `(snippet, phrase)`

Answer (score 4):

It's just a two-trip loop.  On the first iteration, `sentence` is set to `snippet`.  On the second iteration, `sentence` is set to `phrase`.

Here's a simple example:

```
>>> for x in "a", "b":
...     print(x)
...
a
b
>>>
```

Answer (score 3):

This is another syntax (syntactic sugar) for *tuples*, which are an immutable data container. You could have written this like this:

```
for something in (1,2,3,4):
```

But in this case you can omit the parentheses, thus getting:

```
for something in 1,2,3,4:
```

That's also valid syntax.

---

#### Example to try:

```
for X in 1,2,3,4:
    print X
```

> Prints the following:
>
> ```
>  1
>  2
>  3
>  4
> ```

Comment: You mean that the for loop chooses both in snippet and phrase and run the loop?

Comment: @Liuyang, it choses first snippet and then phrase.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am also confused about what is the function of snippet and phrase here?

Comment: @Liuyang, I've got no idea since snippet and phrase are function parameters so _you decide_ what they should contain

Comment: I understand. Thank you very much!

Comment: Omitting the parentheses isn't really syntactic sugar: Python tuple literals are created by the use of commas, but sometimes you may need to enclose a tuple in parentheses to prevent ambiguity, since commas are also used to separate function arguments.

Comment: @PM2Ring, agreed about braces vs parentheses. I'm not a native English speaker, so I'm sometimes making mistakes

Answer (score 0):

A for loop just goes through each item in an iterable collection. So range(5) returns the iterable collection of all items between 0 and 5. The for loop gives you access to that.

```
>>> for x in range(5):
...     print(x)
...
0
1
2
3
4
>>>
```